# Show the set of positive rationals under multiplication is not cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

I want to check if my proof needs any modification:
Let $q$  belong to $\mathbb Q$

Then $\langle q\rangle =e,q,q^2,...$

But there exist no $q$ such that $\langle q\rangle=\mathbb Q\;$  since between every power of $q$ there is a rational $p$ that is not in $\langle q\rangle$

=> no element generates $\mathbb Q$

=> it's not cyclic

Comment: $<q>$ also contains negative powers, i.e. $q^{-1}, q^{-2}, \ldots$.

Comment: Hmm, your proof seems to boil down to _asserting_ what you want to prove, rather than giving an argument for it. If you know that there is always a $p\in\mathbb Q$ that is not in $\langle q\rangle$, then true enough $\mathbb Q$ is not cyclic. But you need to _prove_ that such a $p$ exists for every $q$, rather than just assert authoritatively that it does.

Comment: You seem to be hinting at an argument that, for example, you can find a suitable $p$ in the interval $(q^3,q^4)$. However this is _not always true_: If $q=1$ then this interval is empty! And even if the interval _does_ contain rational numbers you could pick as $p$, you need to argue that your $p$ cannot be equal to $q^n$ for any other $n$.

Comment: $e$ is not an element of $\mathbb Q.$

Comment: @bof e is 1 because the operation is multiplication so 1 is in Q

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that $q\in\mathbb{Q}^+$ generates the group that is
$$\langle q\rangle=\{q^n: n\in\mathbb{Z}\}=\mathbb{Q}^+.$$
Without loss of generality we may assume that $q>1$ (note that  $\langle q\rangle=\langle q^{-1}\rangle$ and $\langle 1\rangle=\{1\}$).

Then
$r=\frac{1+q}{2}\in \mathbb{Q}^+$, but for any positive integer $n$,
$$0<q^{-n}<1<r<q^{n}$$
which means that $r\not\in \langle q\rangle$. Contradiction.